# What are the 2-3 most important parameter that we have to check before buyinh condencer microphone?

Tags: microphone

What are the 2-3 most important parameters that we have to check before buying a condenser microphone?

If we know that the most important things we have to look at computer hardware are: 1) Processor +its generation, 2) RAM, 3) SSD and maybe a graphic card. On this way, what are the most important to look for, for the purpose of home singing recording.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is your first purchase of a condenser mic. If you had a studio with a number of mics already, I guess the question would be different.

First: do you have the soundcard / preamp that will work with condencer mics? Most require a XLR-3 connection and 48V phantom power. If not, there are other solutions. On the other hand, you should be able to get a good enough USB sound card for less than USD 100.

Secondly: does the mic fit your voice and your recording situation? There are so many brands and versions to choose from, and they are more or less different. You probably could not go wrong with a Neumann U87 but it might not be the very best choice (and it does come at a price). For a lot of situations a dynamic mic migth be a better choice -- it is not uncommon to record singers using a Shure SM7 (or even a SM58 ).

Third: what do you want to achieve with the recording. The ideal is quite different if you want to make, say, a death metal recording or recording an opera aria.